# Content of the UIViewController doesn't show up even though the UINavigation bar is there

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, tableview

So I'm trying to switch from one UIViewController to another using the navigation controller. I know for sure that the new controller goes successfully through the custom init method and creates two UIBarButtons. However, the content of the screen (4 labels, 3 textfields, 1 UIImageView) doesn't show up. Instead, I just see a grey screen.

Passing the NSLog message through the ViewDidLoad,ViewWillLoad and ViewWillAppear showed that all these were successfully executed.

Here is the gitHub repo if you want to take a look:
https://github.com/Killavata/Class_Discussion/tree/Stepan

Here is the code that I use to pass a new controller:

```
// Create a new student and add it to the store
  Student* newStudent = [[StudentStore sharedStore] createStudent];

StudentDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[StudentDetailViewController alloc] initForNewStudent:YES];

detailViewController.student = newStudent;

detailViewController.dismissBlock = ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
};

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made the controller in the storyboard, so unless you instantiate it from there (with a segue or instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:), you won't get its view. If you want to use a custom init method, then you either need to make the entire UI in code (in loadView), or make the view in a xib file, load that nib, and set the view to the controller's self.view.

The other approach is to not use a custom init method. Create a property, isNew, and set its value after you instantiate the controller, but before you present it. Check its value in viewDidLoad, and put the code you now have in the init method in viewDidLoad.

Comment: How do I load a nib after I recreated the view in a xib file?

Comment: @Killavat `MyCustomView *myView = [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil][0];` Follow that with `self.view = myView;`